# SQL Column / Row Grouping

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL. I am looking for a simple SQL solution to combine a row/column for row whose column contain the same data, in this case a zip code. For example, the data look looks like this:

```
state, county, city, zip, count

"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94541",5371
"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94542",2209
"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94544",7179
"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94545",4209
"CA","ALAMEDA","CASTRO VALLEY","94546",7213
"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94546",37
"CA","ALAMEDA","LIVERMORE","94550",9809
"CA","ALAMEDA","LIVERMORE","94551",6558
"CA","ALAMEDA","CASTRO VALLEY","94552",3121
"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94552",12
"CA","ALAMEDA","FREMONT","94555",5392
```

I'd like to end up with the data to look like this:

```
state, county, city, zip, count

"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94541",5371
"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94542",2209
"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94544",7179
"CA","ALAMEDA","HAYWARD","94545",4209
"CA","ALAMEDA","CASTRO VALLEY / HAYWARD","94546",7250
"CA","ALAMEDA","LIVERMORE","94550",9809
"CA","ALAMEDA","LIVERMORE","94551",6558
"CA","ALAMEDA","CASTRO VALLEY HAYWARD","94552",3133
"CA","ALAMEDA","FREMONT","94555",5392
```

You can see that in two rows the data has been combined or summed. For rows that contain the exact same zip code, the city names (both) appear in the city column and the count is the sum of the count from each row.

Is there any way to do this using SQL? Even if it requires two different SQL statements that is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming SQL Server, you can use `FOR XML` to get your desired results.

```
select distinct t.state,t.county,t.zip,t2.sumcount,
STUFF(
        (
            SELECT '/' + city AS [text()]
            FROM mytable t3
            WHERE t.zip = t3.zip
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ), 1, 1, '') AS ColList
from mytable t 
  join (select zip, sum(count) as sumcount
       from mytable
       group by zip) t2 on t.zip=t2.zip
```

And some [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8ac2/1).

If you are using MySQL, look at using `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
select distinct t.state,t.county,t.zip,t2.sumcount,
GROUP_CONCAT(t.city) as cities
from mytable t 
  join (select zip, sum(count) as sumcount
       from mytable
       group by zip) t2 on t.zip=t2.zip
GROUP BY t.state,t.county,t.zip,t2.sumcount
```

And more [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8ac2/2).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tweaked sgeddes' superb answer to actually get the count and avoid duplicate entries, and added a support script so you can test it.  This does assume SQL Server.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLE') BEGIN
  drop table MYTABLE;
END;
go

create table MYTABLE
(
  state nvarchar(2)
 ,county nvarchar(100)
 ,city nvarchar(100)
 ,zip nvarchar(10)
)
go

insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94541');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94541');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94544');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94545');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','CASTRO VALLEY','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','CASTRO VALLEY','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','CASTRO VALLEY','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','CASTRO VALLEY','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','CASTRO VALLEY','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94546');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','LIVERMORE','94550');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','LIVERMORE','94551');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','CASTRO VALLEY','94552');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','HAYWARD','94552');
insert into MYTABLE(state,county,city,zip) values('CA','ALAMEDA','FREMONT','94555');

select distinct
  t.state
 ,t.county
 ,t.zip
 ,t2.sumcount
 ,STUFF((
       SELECT distinct '/' + city AS [text()]
       FROM mytable t3
       WHERE t.zip = t3.zip
       FOR XML PATH('')
       ), 1, 1, '') AS ColList
from
  mytable t 
  inner join
  (
  select zip, sum(count) as sumcount
  from
    (
    select zip,count(*) as count
    from mytable
    group by zip
    ) x
  group by zip
  ) t2
  on t.zip=t2.zip
```

The output looks like this:

```
state   county  zip sumcount    ColList
CA  ALAMEDA 94541   2   HAYWARD
CA  ALAMEDA 94544   1   HAYWARD
CA  ALAMEDA 94545   1   HAYWARD
CA  ALAMEDA 94546   9   CASTRO VALLEY/HAYWARD
CA  ALAMEDA 94550   1   LIVERMORE
CA  ALAMEDA 94551   1   LIVERMORE
CA  ALAMEDA 94552   2   CASTRO VALLEY/HAYWARD
CA  ALAMEDA 94555   1   FREMONT
```